# admob ads are not showing in android app apk

Tags: android, admob, apk, ads, adsense

after building the app and install it in my phone the admob ads don't show the banner and the Interstitial ? anyone can help me ?

this is the file i have to change code to show the app

```
 <!-- ADVERTISING VARIABLES ___________________________________________________________________________________________ -->


<!-- Admob settings____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->
<!-- Banner Ad unit id - you should get the banner ad unit id from admob - OPTIONAL - MAY BE LEFT EMPTY TO DISABLE BANNER ADS -->
<string name="BannerAd_unit_id"></string>

<!-- Interstitial Ad unit id - you should get the Interstitial ad unit id from admob - OPTIONAL - MAY BE LEFT EMPTY TO DISABLE INTERSTITIAL ADS -->
<string name="InterstitialAd_unit_id"></string>

<!-- The Interstitial ad can be shown once every 2 gameovers. replace with 1 to show it after every gameover -->
<integer name="ad_shows_every_X_gameovers">1</integer>

<!-- Rate button settings__________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->
<!-- link is created automatically from package. Make sure package id is the same as the one used in google play -->
<string name="unable_to_reach_market">Error reaching market. Please check your internet connection</string>
```

Comment: this file above are only string resources. Please show Your layout xml, Your manifest and the class/Activity where the banner should be shown.

Comment: post your logcat and the Activity in which you are showing the ads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually provide values for your AdUnitIds or Admob cannot serve ads.